# What kind of oil did Jacob use to anoint the pillar in Genesis 28:18?

Tags: genesis, exodus, law, moses, jacob

When Jacob runs away from his brother he comes to Luz where he has an encounter with God at night.In the morning he takes oil and consecrates the stone he had used as a pillow.

Genesis 28:18 NASB

> 18 So Jacob rose early in the morning, and took the stone that he had put [n]under his head and set it up as a pillar and poured oil on its top. 19 He called the name of that place [o]Bethel; however, [p]previously the name of the city had been Luz.

But the ingredients of making oil used for anointing/consecration officials and things is only revealed to Moses some four hundred years later.

Exodus 30:22 NASB

> 22 Moreover, the Lord spoke to Moses, saying, 23 “Take also for yourself the finest of spices: of flowing myrrh five hundred shekels, and of fragrant cinnamon half as much, two hundred and fifty, and of fragrant cane two hundred and fifty, 24 and of cassia five hundred, according to the shekel of the sanctuary, and of olive oil a hin. 25 You shall make [aa]of these a holy anointing oil, a perfume mixture, the work of a perfumer; it shall be a holy anointing oil.

Did Jacob know the ingredients of anointing/consecrating oil or he just used olive oil?

Comment: The Hebrew word _shemen_ (oil) used in Genesis 28:18 is unspecific. I think anything else expressed about this subject would be a matter of opinion, not real evidence.

Comment: I agree with @NigelJ - we are not told so we can say nothing.  However, the most likely material was Jacob had at hand, namely olive oil.

Answer (score 2):

### The Kind of Oil

Although possibly generic in usage.

**Brown-Driver-Briggs**
Under Subtitle 2. a. - suggests [specifically: olive oil](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/8081.htm)

**Wiktionary.org**
Under Hebrew Subtitle 2. - suggests [specifically: cooking oil](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%9F)

### Conclusion

The greasy kind of oil, but olive oil can be used in cooking therefore increasing its probability as the type of oil used on the pillar.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so anointing oil ingredients are given, 500 shekels is roughly 12 lbs, 250  is 6 and so on, add all ingredients into a non transparent bottle with lid pray over it and allow to strengthen over night . Strain all herbs leaving only the fragrant oil that you asked God bless in order for you to preform healing and be a vessel for God to preform  miracles hence showing non believers the way to Htown or heaven

Comment: Hey Jacke, welcome to BHSE, glad to have you with us! We're a little different from other sites that you may know, so if you have time make sure you take our tour (hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks!